# php exec command from file without password

Tags: php, sudoers

I need to exec command from php to write into my `vhosts.conf`.
I have one `add_vhost.sh` file :

```
cat /home/www/test/conf/vhosts.conf >> /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf
```

this is php script:

```
 exec($path_to_add_vhost_sh_file, $output);
```

i want to set no password requirement for `peter` user to exec this file, so i did next thing in my `/etc/sudoers`

`peter ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD:/home/www/test/conf/add_vhost.sh` but its still not working, even in console. *fedora 15*

Comment: your webserver is running under the user "peter"? and you added `sudo` in front of the command in php?

Comment: oh, i see web server is running under www-data :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your webserver runs as the `www-data` user user:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/your/script
```

If not, replace `www-data` by your web server's user name.

In php don't miss to prepend your command line with `sudo`:

```
exec('sudo /path/to/your/script');
```

Comment: This applies of course only if you execute the script via web. (I assumed this). Does it work now?

Comment: yea, and changed webserver user nopasswd in sudoers